# Postgres remote connection timeout works on one machine but not on another

Tags: ip, postgresql, connection, remote

im trying to connect remotely to a postgres database, after opening the connection for my public IP address on the server hosting the database, I was able to connect successfully to the database from my machine but not from the reporting server (windows server 20016) we have.
Its always giving me a time out error message.
Any idea if i should open any port on my local reporting server to be able to connect to the remote postgres database?